# Why does Docker and Heroku push such a huge layer for my small test application?

Tags: php, docker

I'm learning to use Docker and Heroku for my web applications. I've created a very small test PHP application that simply outputs "Hello world". I followed the steps given in the Heroku dev center for deploying Docker-based applications (first with the given example repo, which was fine, and now with my own test app from scratch): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

However, when it comes to running the command,
`heroku container:push web`,
it seems to push a massive layer, more than 200MB. I don't think this is necessary for such a small application and I'm assuming this is a waste of bandwidth. Am I supposed to somehow link my application to an existing image on Heroku? 200MB seems very unnecessary. Everything works fine locally.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Looks like the 7.0-apache base image is 130mb. Your application files are 70mb additional? You can use a slimmer base image if you want a smaller container: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/php/tags/

Comment: Ok, so that would explain the majority of the 200MB. The only application file is index.php which contains the one-liner `<?php echo "hello world";`